# How to horizontally place buttons inside a section

Tags: html, css

I want to place 3 buttons horizontally inside a section
one at the extreme left, another at the extreme right and the third one at the center

something like this
[image]

**CSS code:**

```css
.buttons {
  padding: 1em;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#next {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  background: white;
  color: #00476B;
  border: none;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  width: 100%;
}
#back {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  background: white;
  color: #00476B;
  border: none;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  width: 100%;
}
#submit {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  background: white;
  color: #00476B;
  border: none;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: .buttons{
 padding:1em;
 display: table;
 margin: 0 auto;
 
 
 
 
}


#next{
 margin: auto;
 display: block;
    background: white;
    color: #00476B;
    border: none;
    padding: .5em 1em;
    width: 100%;
    
}

#back{
 margin: auto;
 display: block;
    background: white;
    color: #00476B;
    border: none;
    padding: .5em 1em;
    width: 100%;
     
}

#submit{
 margin: auto;
 display: block;
    background: white;
    color: #00476B;
    border: none;
    padding: .5em 1em;
    width: 100%;
    
}

Comment: Thanks @RahulYadav You should use the *edit* button to add the code into the question. Please also include you HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Just apply your CSS on the buttons to change styles. Wish it works for you.

```css
.button-container{
  text-align:center;

}

.button-container:after{
  clear:both;
  content: "";
}

.btn{
  display:inline-block;
}

.btn-left{
  float:left;
}

.btn-right{
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-container">
  <button class="btn btn-left">Left Button</button>
  <button class="btn btn-centered">Centered Button</button>
  <button class="btn btn-right">Right Button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A combination of `float` and automatic margins will work, as shown in this snippet:

https://jsfiddle.net/0btrggpm/1/

```css
section{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
button{
    width: 50px;
}
#left{
    float:left;
}
#right{
    float:right;
}
#center{
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <button id="left">Left</button>
    <button id="center">Center</button>
    <button id="right">Right</button>
</section>
```

You can add margin to the buttons in order to distantiate them from the edges of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

don't give width 100% to button,just like...

```css
.buttons {
  padding: 1em;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.btn{
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;  
}
#next {
  margin: 0;
  float: right;  
  display: absolute;
  background: #aff;
  color: #00476B;
  border: none;
  padding: .5em 1em;  
}
#back {
  
  display: block;
  float: left;
  background:#aff;
  color: #00476B;
  border: none;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  
}
#submit {
  margin: auto;
  left : 50%;
  display: block;
  background: #aff;
  color: #00476B;
  border: none;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="btn">

<button class="buttons" id="back">Back</button>
<button class="buttons" id="next">Next</button>
<button class="buttons" id="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
</body>
```